# How to create a map (object) from list of strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dictionary

I have an array of many unique strings and I'd like, without looping if at all possible, to create a map object from it where the key for each element is a unique string and the value is defaulted to some arbitrary setting.

Is there a way I can do this in one line without looping? I.e. I want to go from

```
var colours = [ "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet" ];
```

to

```
var colourMap = {
    "Red":    VAL,
    "Orange": VAL,
    "Yellow": VAL,
    "Green":  VAL,
    "Blue":   VAL,
    "Indigo": VAL,
    "Violet": VAL
};
```

Comment: You mention in a comment below that you are looking to optimize this for performance since this code will be code repeatedly. First of all, can't you cache this in a variable in a higher scope? Unless the color list or VAL is going to be different every time there is no reason why you cannot. Second - are you sure performance is a problem? Most of the different techniques (for loop, reduce, forEach, underscore) have very similar performance and are unlikely to be your bottleneck. Profile before micro-optimizing!

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Yes, good points which I will follow up. I suppose my underlying interest here was whether there is a way of doing this that  is not _O(n)_ - It sounds like there isn't.

Comment: JS hardly ever neatly follows those ptime predictions you learned in CS. depending on your needs, Object.create() could be a lot faster.

Comment: I don't think its even theoretically possible for any operations on each element of an unordered array to be less than O(n). However, isn't O(n) the exact case that most algorithms try to get to? Once you're O(n) you're basically in "not a problem" territory.

Comment: sure it is, do some repetitive benchmarks in V8 or TraceMonkey and you'll see what i mean. if the routine is compiled and not runtime optimized, the old rules apply.

Comment: @dandavis haha, you mean due to hotpath caching (or whatever it's called)? Not technically the same thing is it?

Comment: i fail to see a diff between such a benchmark and a repetitive application of string names to a blank object, from the perspective of JS.   wys!=wyg (always) like it does in C... not cut and dry. some take a long time, some take almost no time.

Comment: @dandavis Not sure what you mean but yeah, once you get on a hot path there's all sorts of crazy optimizations that might indeed render repeated callings of an object builder faster (though I'd be interested to know what they might be) in any case, for a single invocation my point is you can't really get better than O(n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **really** want to skip loops altogether (Including functions like `map`), this works:

```
JSON.parse('{"'+colours.join('":"VAL", "')+'":"VAL"}');
```

This builds a JSON string, then parses it.

However, I wouldn't use this function. It's ugly, inefficient, hard to maintain, uses loops "under the hood", and it's generally bad form. (I'm not even gonna bother with `eval` instead of JSON. `eval === evil`).

Go for something like `map` instead:

```
var colours = [ "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet" ];
var colourMap = {};
colours.forEach(function(c){
    colourMap[c] = "VAL";
});
```

Yes, it's looping through the `colours`, but it's more efficient, and easier to understand.

Regarding performance:

`map` and `reduce` [seem to be similar](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-reduce-1) in execution speed (`reduce` is slightly faster), in Google Chrome.

Comment: Just a small note: Obviously it will not work with all possible VALs

Comment: Yea, the JSON option has to result in valid JSON. Some VALs might break it. (And that's one of the reasons it's a bad option)

Comment: JSON.parse uses loops internally so still looping. If you *really* want to avoid loops you can eval but that is getting so over the top pedantic its absurd.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your browser requirements support [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
colours.reduce(function(obj, c){ 
  obj[c] = "VAL";
  return obj;
}, {})
```

or if you're ok with being a jerk and using syntax most js devs aren't even aware exists

```
colours.reduce(function(obj, c){ return (obj[c] = "VAL", obj) }, {})
```

Comment: The Syntax is ok and I like this solution, +1!

Comment: @Cerbrus some languages call it `fold`, `foldl` or `aggregate`, all the same concept.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with jQuery:

```
colourMap = $.map(colours, function(e){
  return { e: "VAL" };
});
```

or with Underscore:

```
var colourMap = {};
_.each(some_object_array, function(val) {
  colourMap[val] = "VAL";
});
```

Or even better (Thanks to George Mauer):

```
_.object(_.map(colourMap, function(c) { return [c, "VAL"] }))
```

Comment: With underscore: `_.object(_.map(colourMap, function(c) { return [c, "VAL"] }))` Usually I use this pattern so much that I do `_.mixin({ mapObject: _.compose(_.object, _.map) })`

Comment: Those are still loops, technically.

Comment: Uhm I think your code produce an array of objects, one for each of the colors. Each one has only 1 key...

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I don't have access to jQuery. Pragmatically, I suppose even a one liner could be looping under the covers. I'm really looking for the most efficient way of doing this since it's code which will be called quite frequently.

Comment: To @AndreaParodi's point, the jquery example above does not produce what you're after, you would have to do `colourMap = $.extend.apply($, ...)` to get it all into one object